# How can change Table Header Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to dynamically change the header of a table based on the **highlighted row data**. Like if we assume the user selects USA in the first column then the other column header should be changed to the states within USA. All the countries and their corresponding states are in a **key array** and the based on the selected country *the header and the column count has to change* like

```
<tr>
     <th>Alabama</th>
     <th>Alaska</th>
</tr>
```

this how the header should look when USA in first row first column is selected.

```
<tr id="1"><td>USA</td></tr>
```

and when row 2 = UK 
          headers should be "MOYLE","Greater LONDON" and so on...

How Can I do this ???

Comment: Share your code stuff you did for this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the user to click the table data cells to highlight?
because then it could be quite easy. 
you give each td an attribute that you requery in jQuery similar to:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    $country = $(this).attr('country');
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    $('tr.states').empty;
    for each item in $myarrayStates['$country']{
     $('tr.states').append("<td>"&$myarrayStates&"</td>")
    }});
```

while the html looks something like

```
<tr class="countries">
    <td country="USA">USA</td>
    <td country="UK">Great Britain</td>
    <td country="DE">Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr class="states">
    <td state="Alabama">Alabama</td>
</tr>
```

then the only thing left is to make sure there is enough space for the tablerows, but i leave that to you
Sorry if i missed the point but i am not quite sure what you want it to look like :(